# How to create a proof of existence runtime in a private network?

Tags: substrate

I am trying to combine the two tutorials from the substrate developer hub:
https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/build-a-dapp/
https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/start-a-private-network/

The network seems to have a correct setup (peers can recognise each other, blocks are being produced and finalised) and the poe pallet is added to the runtime.

However when i send a transaction `api.tx.templateModule.createClaim(digest)` from either polkadot api or polkadot ui, the response is invalid transaction and the runtime error is

`ERROR runtime  panicked at 'Bad input data provided to apply_extrinsic: ~/substrate/runtime/src/lib.rs:318:1'`.

I am using the substrate-node-template, the private network topology is 4 nodes and all of them are validators with their addresses in the `customSpec.json` both in Aura and Grandpa authorities.

What am I missing?

Comment: `Bad input data provided to ..` is generated when the data that you are passing to the runtime cannot be decoded. In this case, this would mean the transaction and its arguments.

Comment: ```const hash: string = blake2AsHex(context, 256);

const node1: AddressOrPair = keyring.addFromUri(PHRASE);

  const claim = api.tx.templateModule.createClaim(hash);

  const unsub = await claim.signAndSend(node1);```

How can this be wrong input data?

Comment: Also how do I know if the problem is with the data passed or the signature?